# How to determine which machine is eating bandwidth

Tags: monitoring, netgear-prosafe

Network setup:

Router: Netgear FVS318N
Switch: Netgear GS752TP
There are two wireless APs connected to the switch, as well as about 15 wired devices, and about 10 wireless devices.

Looking for a way to determine which wireless client is using up bandwidth.

Comment: First, define what you mean by eating up the bandwidth. Do you mean outboud or inbound traffic?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If all of your devices (and the AP) are connected on the switch Netgear GS752TP and this connected to the router Netgear FVS318N, you could do a mirroring-port on the port between the switch and the router to a free port.

After, you could capture all the traffic of your devices with what you want (tcpdump, wireshark) and see which device eats your bandwith. You could save your traffic in pcap format and analyse later. With wireshark, for example, you could list all your devices with their bandwith.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't give any details, I will have to make some assumptions.

First, I assume you mean that the wireless clients are having difficulties, and you assume that it is a particular client using a lot of bandwidth.  Your assumption may be incorrect.  You may be experiencing wireless interference.  Always start troubleshooting at layer-1, which, in this case, is the airwaves.  You need to get a hardware/software combination that can sniff the airwaves to see what is actually happening.

Next, you can use the router/firewall's logging facility to look at the traffic to and from the Internet.  If your problem is inbound, you can look to see if you are experiencing a DoS, or look at the destination addresses to see if one of the devices is streaming some sort of video or something.  If the problem is outbound, you can look at the source addresses to see which device is sending an inordinate amount of traffic.

Comment: I may very well be incorrect... it happens :)  I have one user that has 5 devices.  When they are not connected, the rest of the clients have no issues, however, once they do connect up w start to see degraded performance.  I had installed ntopng, but am unable to view wireless client traffic with that (wired LAN is viewable).  Then I thought I could plug into the monitoring port of the switch, but don't know if that would give me the visibility that I was looking for.

Comment: You need to get something that can sniff the airwaves. There are turnkey devices or software packages for computers and smartphones designed for this. If the traffic is headed to or from the Internet, the logging on your router/firewall can tell you about that.